# Templates in Polymer 2, how to get context of the slot element?

Tags: javascript, polymer, shadow-dom

Is there any way to execute methods from a `slot`'ed element?      I'm creating a template which contain an save button. Ideally the template should call the slotted content (the child) *.save* method when his own save button has been clicked. Any ideas on how to achieve this ?

I've tried the following *template*:

```
<dom-module id="template-action-bar">
  <template>
    <style include="granite-bootstrap"></style>

    <slot id="slot"></slot> 

    <div class="container flex-end-justified">
      <button
       hidden$=[[_isNotFn('next')]]
       disabled$="[[!valid]]"
       class="btn btn-primary"
       on-click="_next"
      >
        Next (Save)
      </button>

      <button
        hidden$=[[_isNotFn('back')]]
        disabled$="[[!valid]]"
        class="btn btn-primary"
        on-click="_back"
      >
        Back (Undo)
      </button>
   </div>
</template>
    <script>
    class TemplateActionBar extends Organism {
      static get is() {
        return 'template-action-bar';
      }

      static get properties() {
        return {
          next: Function,
          back: String
        };
      }

      _isNotFn(fn) {
        return this[fn] !== 'function';
      }

      _next() {
        this.next();
      }

      _back() {
        this.$.slot.undo();
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(TemplateActionBar.is, TemplateActionBar);
    </script>
```

And the *element* (short version of it):

```
<dom-module id="element-creation">
  <template>
    <template-action-bar
      next="{{ save }}"
    >
    <!-- ....... -->
  </template>

  <script>
  class ElementCreation extends Organism {
    /* ****************** */

    save() {
      // FIRST ATTEMPT
      console.log(this); // <- I want the scope of ElementCreation not template-action-bar
    }

    save() {
      // SECOND TRY
      return (function() {
        console.log(this); // <- I want the scope of ElementCreation not template-action-bar
      }());
    }
  }
  window.customElements.define(ElementCreation.is, ElementCreation);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have a specific code related issue?

Comment: I've posted an example. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you can slot any element, even elements that do not have the `save` method, IMO this is not the proper way to achieve this. Polymer heavily relies on the mediator pattern. Instead, you should fire an event when the save button is clicked, and act on this event in the mediator (i.e., the component that instantiates the element with slots, and the slotted elements.

```
class ElementWithSlots {
  ...
  onSaveTap_(event) {
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('saved', {bubbles: false}));
  }
}
```

Then, in your mediator:

```
<element-with-slots on-saved="onSavedEvent_">
  <slotted-element id="slotted" slot="foo"></slotted-element>
</element-with-slots>
```

And in your mediator JS:

```
onSavedEvent_ {
  this.$.slotted.actOnSave();
}
```